# Killing a sub-subprocess from python/bash without leaving orphans

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, subprocess

I have a system with 3 main components (everything running on Ubuntu14.04 and Python 2.7, don't care too much about portability):

a) Some binary that executes, let's call it `runtime`, it writes some values to `stdout` and `stderr` that I need to read from (c)

b) A launcher script that set's up the environment and executes `runtime`, let's call it `launcher`, it looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

#Needed by the runtime
export SOME_VAR=1234 
source some_file.sh
#...
exec runtime --option1 $1 --option2 $2
```

c) A server, it handles remote requests and calls the `launcher` when a remote client requests it. The server is written in python and needs to read the `stdX` from (a). I'm calling `launcher` using the subprocess module:

```
# When calling the launcher script:
cmd = "launcher value1 value2"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, 
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
    shell=True)
# read p.stdout ...
```

This creates 2 new processes, 1 for the `launcher` script (e.g. pid:10000) and other for the `runtime` (e.g. pid:10001), running `htop` with `tree` shows something similar to this:

```
PID    ...  Command
12345  ...  python server.py
10000  ...    |- /bin/sh -c ./launcher value1 value2
10001  ...        |- runtime --option1 value1 --option2 value2
```

At some point, the `server` want's to stop the `runtime` process (by sending a `SIGTERM`)

```
# When trying to stop the runtime:
os.kill(p.pid, signal.SIGTERM)
# Have also tried with p.terminate(), same results.
```

The problem is that this only kills the `launcher` process (pid:10000), leaving the `runtime` executing indefinitely. I want to properly propagate the `SIGTERM` to the `runtime` whenever the `server` requests it (`runtime` MUST receive this signal to stop and exit gracefully, otherwise it will produce data corruption).

I've tried using `os.killpg(...)` to kill the whole process group, but it also kills the `server` (obviously).

**How can I properly propagate a SIGTERM signal to a sub-sub-process?**

Comment: Maybe using process groups will help you here?  You can kill an entire process group in bash with `kill -SIGTERM -$PGID`, or in python with `os.pgkill()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use process group this way:

```
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
                    shell=True, preexec_fn=os.setpgrp)

os.killpg(os.getpgid(p.pid), signal.SIGTERM)
```